# ASP.NET Web Forms dropdownlist option innerText

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm newbie in `ASP.NET Web Froms` and I want to get an `innerText` of selected option in a `dropDownList`. I've written the following code snippet in the `default.aspx`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
```

and in the code-behind I've written

```
statsTitle.innerText=ddlBlog.Text;
```

But this line set a value attribute of selected `<option>` tag.

Comment: Can you show statsTitle?

Comment: what is statsTitle????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
string a = ddl.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `SelectedItem` property, like :

```
statsTitle.innerText=ddlBlog.SelectedItem.ToString();
```